# maven error : pom.xml is without errors in editor but clean install fails because of errors in pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml, xsd-validation

contents of my pom are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project >


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.carleton</groupId>
    <artifactId>cep-monitoring</artifactId>
    <name>cep-monitoring</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>



    <properties>

        <flink.version>1.3.2</flink.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

         <!-- loggers related-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Streaming related-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cep library -->

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-cep_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- connectors-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- metrices related -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-metrics-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-metrics-dropwizard</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-metrics-statsd</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-metrics-datadog</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--just for generating some random numbers
        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objectledge.maven.plugins/jsc-maven-plugin &ndash;&gt;
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objectledge.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>



    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                        <version>0.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.codehaus.plexus.util</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.shaded.plexus.util</shadedPattern>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>


    </build>>


</project>
```

When I try to execute `mvn clean install` i get following error

```
    amar@admin:~/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP Architectures/Mobile CEP$ mvn clean install -X
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.0/3.0.5/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.0/3.0.5/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/amar/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/amar/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /Users/amar/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.carleton:cep-monitoring:jar:1.0: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM /Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP Architectures/Mobile CEP/pom.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</plugins>\n\n\n    </build>>\n\n\n</... @227:3)  @ /Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP Architectures/Mobile CEP/pom.xml, line 227, column 3

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
```

Comment: See also the root reason for this in my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the closing build tag `</build>>`.

There is an extra `>` which is interpreted as text.

I think editor should complain about this but it does not, not in my Eclipse.

**Update**: the reason for editor happily accepted was that i just copy pasted your pom.

You have:

```
<project>
```

at the start of your pom.

it should be something like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

The `schemaLocation` tells the editor how to validate AND tell you about these kind of errors.

Add that and see the if your editor sees the problem before building.